# How to configure Java for Jenkins on Ubuntu

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a VM with Ubuntu 18.04 with JDK 12 as default java in it. I want to setup a Jenkins server on it and as it do not support JDK 12 yet, i have installed JRE 8 in it to support Jenkins.

How to configure Jenkins such that it will use this JRE8 instead of JDK12??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After understanding how Jenkins allows us to override configuration and debugging init script, i found multiple ways to tackle this situation.

1. Override PATH variable in /etc/default/jenkins(I prefer this solution)
   PATH=<PATH to your JAVA>
2. Modify PATH variable in /etc/init.d/jenkins(prefix your path  to java)
   PATH=<PATH to your JAVA>:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
3. Force Jenkins to use Java that you specify in /etc/init.d/jenkins
   JAVA='<PATH to your JAVA>/java'

Note: <PATH to your JAVA> is an absolute path to your java location
        For E.g. 1. /usr/lib/jvm//bin in case of JDK
                2. /usr/lib/jvm//jre/bin in case of JRE

Answer (score 0):

Since systemd came around, we can override `JENKINS_JAVA_CMD` in a drop-in file:

`/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/override.conf`

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_JAVA_CMD=/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64/bin/java"
```

And run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart jenkins.service
```

`/etc/default/jenkins` and `/etc/init.d/jenkins` seem to be entirely ignored.